# Require paths for rspec tests in a Ruby Gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I am creating a simple Ruby Gem which is currently laid out as per the example in the [Making your own gem](http://guides.rubygems.org/make-your-own-gem/#requiring-more-files) documentation.

My directory structure:

```
.
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── lib
│   ├── go_run
│   │   ├── parser.rb
│   │   └── runner.rb
│   └── go_run.rb
└── spec
    ├── go_run_spec.rb
    ├── parser_spec.rb
    └── runner_spec.rb
```

I originally called the `Runner` class in `lib/go_run/runner.rb` just `Runner`, but now, as per the documented example I have namespaced it under `GoRun::Runner`. The code works. The problem is that now running `bundle exec rspec spec/parser_spec.rb` does not. It fails with:

```
/home/smurf/dev/ruby/go_run/lib/go_run/parser.rb:3:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant GoRun (NameError)
```

The 3rd line of that file is:

```
class GoRun::Parser
```

I am `require`ing the library code in `spec/parser_spec.rb` using `require 'go_run/parser'`.

I tried including it with `require_relative '../lib/go_run/parser'`, but that produced the same error.

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

**Update:** I have uploaded the complete code on this branch: https://github.com/henrytk/go_run/tree/stackoverflow-43155117

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is originating in `lib/go_run/parser.rb` rather than from the test itself. Whenever Ruby finds the `GoRun::Parser` definition, it goes looking for `GoRun` in the constant lookup table, but it won't be there, and so the program exits with an error.

Note that using `lib/go_run.rb` as an entry point also will not work, because `go_run/parser.rb` is required *before* `GoRun` is defined.

Part of the problem is using `GoRun` as *both* the project level namespace, and an entry point `class`.

---

There are a couple of idioms you should consider to fix this situation:

1. Make `GoRun` a top level `module`, used purely for namespacing. Move the logic that lives in the current logic into its own `class`, for example `go_run/cli.rb`. The `go_run.rb` file is then kept as a sort of manifest file, that requires the classes of your project.
2. Use the nested `module`- and `class` syntax. This will define the outer module if it isn't already.
3. Use a `spec_helper.rb` file that bootstraps your project using `require 'go_run'`, to make sure everything is properly loaded before running your tests.

Comment: Thanks @Drenmi. I only wanted to namespace it under `GoRun::Parser` because that is how the documentation did it, do you know why it is done that way? What would be the harm of just leaving it as `Parser`?

Comment: You'll need to consider that your gem will live together both with other libraries and user code. If they, or any of their other gems (like RuboCop), have a dependency on the Parser gem, you will have a naming conflict. :-)

Comment: Excellent. My Gem is intended to be used only for its executable `run`, not as a library, so I don't expect anyone to actually `require 'go_run'` in their code, just `gem install` and use it. Thank you for your help.